# Why does solr add new document while updating?

Tags: solr

```
curl 'http://localhost/solr/collection/update?commit=true' 
-H 'Content-type:application/json' 
-d 
'[ 
  { 
    "id":"11111", 
    "price":{"set":1000} 
  }
]'
```

If id:11111 exists, price value is updated. **It's ok.**

If id:11111 doesn't exist, new document is created in solr index. This behavior is not desirable. I expect error with some text like: *document you tried to update does not exist.*
I cannot understand what is wrong.

**Solr version: 4.8.0.**

**Part of schema.xml:**

```
<field name="id" type="string"  indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Comment: Any feedback ? Do you understand why you don't get the expected behavior and why does solr add new document 'while updating' ?

Comment: I decided to modify my workflow as you adviced me in your answer. 

I only wonder why this behavior is default? Why is it not restful?

Comment: This is restful in that the /update handler function is to update the index as a whole, the API provide operations like add/replace, delete, commit, optimize, etc.. The advantage I think is the possibility to perform several operations (e.g add, delete & commitWithin) in a single batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/update` request handler actually updates the index for new and existing documents and handles deletion as well.

During indexation:

- A document is considered new if it has no identifier or if its id does not match any of the indexed documents. If no id is generated during indexing and if the uniqueKey field is required, the document is rejected.
- A document that has an identifier matching an indexed document is merged with its stored version : all stored fields are loaded from the index and are overriden by field values from the request parameters, and the resulting document replace the previous one (but in the end it is the same operation).

In other word an update request - if not a *delete* - always ends up in the same *add* operation. By the way the XML schema recognized by `solr.UpdateRequestHandler` contains the elements **`<add>`**, `<doc>` and `<field>` regardless of the operation (add or replace).

Recent versions of Solr provide more options for updating parts of documents. (see [atomic updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-AtomicUpdates) and [in-place updates](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-In-PlaceUpdates).

What you describe is the expected behavior. Since the `id` field is required, Solr will throw an error for document missing this field. In your situation, the document is indexed in both cases because the id is given in both cases.

With this configuration you would have to ensure that `id` field is empty for what you consider a new document, either client side when preparing the request or server side using an update processor or by updating the request handler implementation. Maybe it would be even simpler to prevent the indexation of any new docs ?

Answer (score 0):

that is how the current implementation of Atomic updates seems to work. I concur it might be desirable to get an error...You should raise the issue in the user mailing list, and see what commiters think, maybe they agree with you that an error should be raised, they'll ask you to open a jira then.

Oh, just noticed the 4.8 version, that is quite old, can you by any chance test the behaviour in current versions?

Comment: no, it's still the same api, it's just a bad luck, that this handler is called update handler, while it more means createORupdateANDdelete handler